# Can gravity be controlled?

Tags: gravity

Humans might naturally be able to manipulate the gravity around us with our bodies and control it and focus it for propulsion uses. This is just a guess. So my question is, is it possible for a human to naturally manipulate the gravity around it and control it to propel or move around?

Comment: Technically you can increase the strength of the gravitational field around you (very, very, infinitesimally) by putting on a lot of weight. Sadly that is unlikely to help you much in the way of movement/ propulsion.

Comment: This is more proper to Physics SE (although in fact it is likely off-topic there as it lacks any attempt to research an answer yourself  and would also fall foul of the no personal theories rule ).  But it's not Worldbuilding.

Answer (score 4):

The universe has 4 known forces that we know of. Two of them play a role in the high energy/high density world of nuclear matter and other exotic states of matter.

The other two are gravitation and electromagnetism. We've learned to  build and manipulate devices for propulsion via the electromagnetic force, mainly due to two main reasons:

- the EM force posseses two different charges, positive and negative, those can be combined to shield or reverse the action of the EM force.
- Small qantities of charges are enough to create huge forces

Those two properties, taken together the multitudes of atoms and molecules that nature knows, are enough to build all devices you know today. Note that chemistry is also simply electromagnetism + quantum mechanics.

Now on one hand, the gravitational force doesn't have any of the two properties mentioned above. It has solemnly positive charges (mass) and shifting around a bunch of those charges doesn't create large forces.

On the other hand, the human body is held together by chemistry and thus in the end by electromagnetism. I don't see how this should interact with gravity, so that one would 'naturally' manipulate the latter.

That's the science behind it. But you of course can magic something up.

Answer (score 2):

@AtmosphericPrisonEscape has clearly described the reasons why we cannot currently manipulate gravity.  None of the elements or energies which we have encountered so far have exhibited any effect on gravity except by their own mass.  This includes the materials and energies which make up our own human bodies.

However, the universe is a very big place and we have only explored an infinitesimal part of it. We cannot rule out the possibility that some gravity reactive matter or energy exists out there beyond our current reach.  It is possible that we may someday find such materials and with them, unlock the science of manipulating gravity.  If and when we do, those materials will be as integral to that science, as conductive and semi-conductive elements are to the science of manipulating electromagnetism.

Your question however, has asked if humans can have any unusual (or useful) effect on gravity, and we have access to a very large percentage (possibly all) of the humans in the universe. So far, we have perceived none of the power or influence which you are looking for.

So I am afraid that barring magic (or a nearly equivalent shift in the physical laws of the universe), the answer is no.  Humans cannot naturally manipulate gravity.

Answer (score 1):

If you were near infinitely strong/durable you could row a rowboat in a vacuum if the tips of your (also near infinitely durable) oars are approaching the speed of light during your pull stroke thereby propelling yourself by generating gravitational waves.

> So my question is, is it possible for a human to naturally manipulate
>   the gravity around it and control it to propel or move around?

Only if said "human" is some sort of super-saiyan-superman-hulk-thing.